# Pix-elated Drawing and 3D representations

Tags: c#, opengl

I am writing a program to imitate Natural Physics. I want to know whether there is a better way to draw an object other than overriding the `OnDraw` method, and `FillRectangle(x,y,1,1)` for each pixel.

Is there a way to do a similar action using DirectX or OpenGL? Because to my knowledge the `Graphics` does not utilize the video card of ones computer (please correct me if I am wrong).

Saying this I would like some thoughts in relation to creating a 3D environment using mathematical calculations to work out the relative quadrant sizes so that objects appear to be farther away then in reality (as a monitor is only 2D), or closer.

Comment: Your question is far too vague. Define "*better*", What do you need to do, and what is wrong with `FillRectangle(x,y,1,1)` for your needs?

Comment: I have defined what I need, I am looking for information on the GDI+ and whether it is efficient to use it for drawing or should I use something else, what I mean by efficient is, does it use the appropriate hardware and to what degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Drawing pixel by pixel with FillRectangle will be very inefficient and slow things down a huge amount. As you say, you should use a graphics rendering system such as DirectX or OpenGL. The choice of which is up to you. If you do a simple search on the web you will find many tutorials on how to get started with 3d graphics.

OpenGL focuses on "Draw me this object in space", and it will take care of rendering it, taking advantage of your graphics card if possible. You do not worry about the pixels, you specify dimensions, camera angles, shaders etc.

You can draw pixels with OpenGL, but that is not the 'correct' way to draw 3d graphics with it.

EDIT in response to Vasa's questions:

I believe OpenGL does what's best based on your graphics card capabilities and drivers. In general OpenGL isn't going to be your best option for drawing direct pixels. BUT remember that

1. Pixels are different sizes on different machines. Are you expecting to just live with this? Or live with a big display on low-res screens and a tiny one on high-res screens? There may be multiplications involved. If you use literal pixels then once you start multiplying for different screens you are going to get artefacts and inaccuracies.
2. You want a direct mapping of X to pixels. OpenGL uses float values. They aren't integer 1 to 1 mappings, but they do use a direct proportion. If you choose a scale then OpenGL is not going to suddenly start distorting ratios.

The important thing is proportions not absolute pixels. Although I accept that it's possible for your case to be different.

See this for 2d drawing:

http://basic4gl.wikispaces.com/2D+Drawing+in+OpenGL

Comment: The reason I wanted to draw pixels is that I can make a very accurate physics simulator. A pixel will be equal to a certain distance, and the whole virtual environment will be stored in an array, in which an object will be travelling say a projectile. 

I found the easiest way to to do what I want and with the accuracy I want is to use pixel perfect graphics (or the like). 

How would I go about drawing the pixels in OpenGL? Also would there be a way to for OpenGL to use the graphics card, or is it self-regulating (if more processing power is needed it switches to using the G-Card).

Comment: I answered your comment in my answer.

Comment: I think I may still be able to use this to my advantage, but it will take some time to get my head around a new concept in doing it this way. I am thinking something along the lines of: A projectile travelling in the VE and in the VE Array will access the VE array, to check the corresponding relative position on screen to its position in the array and decide whether it have hit anything. I may have to learn OpenGL to get the hang of this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Good luck! Remember that the simulation of objects and the visual representation of this are/can be completely separated.